# C++ boost PP get set difference on 2 sequence?

Tags: c++, boost, preprocessor

How to get set difference on Boost PP seq by macro function?
For example, I have

```cpp
#define FRUIT (apple)(banana)(pear)(orange)
#define EAT (banana)(orange)

#define REST (apple)(pear)
```

How Could I get boost pp seq: `REST`?

Comment: This is only possible if you can predefine all possible elements. So you'd need to define something like `#define EQ_apple_apple ,1` for every possible element. Would this be possible with with your problem?

Comment: It's a greate idea to get string compare result in c++ macro.

Comment: Finally I use python to generate all combinations of NOT case, for example, ```#define NOT_banana_orange apple,pear``` since I known all items in my case. If there are unlimited items, I do not think macro set difference is a solution here, maybe convert type to typeid and use std::set is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to compare strings in preprocessor. You have to create a dictionary with all possible comparisons. With the help of `BOOST_PP_EQUAL` the dictionary can just map the values to the range between 0 to BOOST_PP_LIMIT_MAG.

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>

#define FRUIT (apple)(banana)(pear)(orange)
#define EAT (banana)(orange)

// Dictionary
#define V_apple   0
#define V_banana  1
#define V_pear    2
#define V_orange  3
#define TO_V(x)   V_##x

// If elements from lists match, output '1' anything, otherwise nothing.
#define COMPARE(r, data, elem)  \
        BOOST_PP_IF(BOOST_PP_EQUAL(TO_V(data), TO_V(elem)), 1, )
// If any element matches EAT, output 0, otherwise 1.
#define FILTER(s, data, elem)  \
        BOOST_PP_IS_EMPTY(BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(COMPARE, elem, data))
// Just filter.
BOOST_PP_SEQ_FILTER(FILTER, EAT, FRUIT)
```